# Transmission of the structure through modbus

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, network-programming, modbus

I need to receive some structure with parameters from a server. This server is an stm32 controller.
On the stm32 side, I'll convert struct to bytes and place that in registers. On the computer side, I'll read bytes from all registers and convert them to structure.

Is it possible? What is the true way instead of this way?

For example:

```
struct MachineParameters
{
  int acceleration;
  int distance;
  int moment[30];
  int values[30];
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What does that random struct have to do with anything? What's your exact problem, more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use serial or TCP Modbus? Depending on this, you'd either need a serial Modbus Driver or a socket based approach to Modbus. Both precede packages with a few protocol bytes overhead - again, things depend upon the driver you use. For using the same header on both sides of a modbus connection, make your structs "packed". Otherwise, the packet lengths might differ on both sides. As long as you are using int, this is not a problem, but once you use a char or a short, you might get packing bytes.

Comment: I use a TCP Modbus. Thanks.